# Selenium is entering 9.888888888E9 as phone number after getting it from excel

Tags: java, selenium

I have name, number, email etc in my excel which I am retrieving using the below code

Phone number in excel is 9888888888

```
v=wb.getSheet(sheet).getRow(r).getCell(c).toString();
```

but when I run my script to enter the data, selenium is entering 9.888888888E9.
I have tried formatting the cell in excel to "Text", "Number" but it has not worked.
How do I get it to enter the number as is in the excel?

Comment: [DataFormatter](https://poi.apache.org/apidocs/dev/org/apache/poi/ss/usermodel/DataFormatter.html) might help you,

Comment: @Newtoselenium which method in the accepted answer worked for you. If you tried the 2 for numeric, did the if/else have any lag, probably milliseconds but good to know

Comment: if (wb.getSheet(sheet).getRow(r).getCell(c).getCellType() == Cell.CELL_TYPE_NUMERIC) {
    v = NumberToTextConverter.toText(wb.getSheet(sheet).getRow(r).getCell(c).getNumericCellValue());
} else if (wb.getSheet(sheet).getRow(r).getCell(c).getCellType() == Cell.CELL_TYPE_STRING) {
    v = wb.getSheet(sheet).getRow(r).getCell(c).getStringCellValue();
} this worked

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Seleniun `sendKeys()` doesn't have any function to convert the text. It just passes the values into destination. You need to change the method of getting value from excel. Please try below possible solutions,

```
v=wb.getSheet(sheet).getRow(r).getCell(c).getStringCellValue();
```

or

```
v=wb.getSheet(sheet).getRow(r).getCell(c).getRawValue();
```

or

```
if (wb.getSheet(sheet).getRow(r).getCell(c).getCellType() == Cell.CELL_TYPE_NUMERIC) {
    v = NumberToTextConverter.toText(wb.getSheet(sheet).getRow(r).getCell(c).getNumericCellValue());
} else if (wb.getSheet(sheet).getRow(r).getCell(c).getCellType() == Cell.CELL_TYPE_STRING) {
    v = wb.getSheet(sheet).getRow(r).getCell(c).getStringCellValue();
}
```